# python pandas automatic excel lookup system

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I know this is alot of code and there is alot to do, but i am really stuck and don't know how to continue after i got the function that the program can match identical files. I am pretty sure you know how the lookup from excel works. This Program does basicly the same. I tried to comment out the important parts and hope you can give me some help how i can continue this project. Thank you very much!

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

File1 = pd.read_excel("Excel_test.xlsx", usecols=[0], header=None, index=False) #the two excel files with the columns that should be compared
File2 = pd.read_excel("Excel_test02.xlsx", usecols=[0], header=None, index=False)

fullFile1 = pd.read_excel("Excel_test.xlsx", header=None, index=False)#the full excel files 
fullFile2 = pd.read_excel("Excel_test02.xlsx",  header=None, index=False)


i = 0

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx")

def loadingTime(): #just a loader that shows the percentage of the matching process
    global i
    loading = (i / len(File1)) * 100
    loading = round(loading, 2)
    print(str(loading) + "%/100%")

def matcher():
    global i
    while(i < len(File1)):#goes in column that should be compared and goes on higher if there is a match found in second file
        for o in range(len(File2)):#runs through the column in second file
            matching = File1.iloc[i].str.lower() == File2.iloc[o].str.lower() #matches the column contents of the two files
            if matching.bool() == True:
                print("Match")
                """
                df.append(File1.iloc[i])#the whole row of the matched column should be appended in Dataframe with the arrangement of excel file
                df.append(File2.iloc[o])#the whole row of the matched column should be appended in Dataframe with the arrangement of excel file
                """
        i += 1

matcher()

df.to_excel(writer, "Sheet")
writer.save() #After the two files have been compared to each other, now a file containing both excel contents and is also arranged correctly
```

Comment: Are you trying to compare two columns in two different Excel files, and if two cells from the two files match, then append both rows from file1, and file2 to a new file?

Comment: Yes exactly! That's how it should work.